# Find the order of the elements in the given groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to find the order of the following elements in the given groups:

- $(1 \ \ 2 \ \ 3) \ (1 \ \ 2\ \ 4) \text{ in } S_5$
  $$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2  & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
  3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 5
  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 3
  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 4
  \end{pmatrix}$$ order $=\operatorname{lcm}(2,2)=2$

Is it correct?

- $a^{45}$ in $G=\langle a\mid a^{140}=1\rangle$
  $$\operatorname{ord}(a^{45})=\frac{140}{\gcd(45, 140)}=\frac{140}{5}=28$$

Is it right?

- $\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & -1\\ 
  1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} \text{ in } GL_2(\mathbb{R})$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}  \\ A^2=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}  \\ A^3=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

But how can I find the order?

Comment: The last computation is clearly wrong, because the matrix $A$ is invertible, so it can't be nilpotent. However, what's $A^4=(A^2)^2$? That shouldn't be difficult and it would tell you the order of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The first two computations are correct.

The matrix $A$ is invertible (because $\det A=1$), so $A^3$ can't be the zero matrix. Once you found that $A^2=-I_2$ ($I_2$ the identity matrix), you know that $A^4=(A^2)^2=I_2^2=\dots$

Thus you know the order of $A$, because…

Comment: Ahaa... So, since $A^4=I_2$, we have that the order is equal to $ord(A)=4$.. Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: @MaryStar Yes: we know that, if $g^n=1$ (with $n>0$), then the order of $g$ divides $n$.

Comment: So, we have that $4 \mid ord(A)$. Since $A^m \neq I_2, m<4$, we have that $ord(A)=4$. Is this correct??

Comment: @MaryStar No: since $A^4=I_2$, we have that $\operatorname{ord}(A)\mid 4$. But $A\ne I_2$ and $A^2\ne I_2$, so the order must be $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two questions are indeed correct.

Note that your calculation of $A^3$ is "off":

$$A^3= A^2 A=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

And $A^4 = A^2A^2 = -I\cdot -I = I$. Hence the order of $A = 4$.

Comment: Can I ask in what this answer differs from mine?

Comment: Ahaa... Thank you for your help!!